# How to create transition effect using js as hover detector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a drop-down menu with some trasition effect(with opacity). Here's the my code:

```js
function show(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  x.style.display = "block";
  x.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
#parent1 {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 40%;
  color: white
}
#par {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
.as {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
hr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul>li>ul {
  /* this is "child" */
  color: rgb(15, 22, 98);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
  background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0 7px -1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent1">
  <ul id="par" type="none">
    <li class="as">a</li>
    <hr/>
    <li class="as">b</li>
    <hr/>
    <li class="as" onmouseover="show('child')">c
      <ul id="child" type="none">
        <li class="ass1">1</li>
        <li class="ass1">2</li>
        <li class="ass1">3</li>
        <li class="ass1">4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <hr/>
    <li class="as">d</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiureznicencu/61haxkh2/).
 I want to create a transition effect from opacity 0 to 1 and aplly it only to the second "ul".

But the transition is not working. I checked the js and it's ok. But why isn't the effect working? Thanks in advance and sorry for my mistakes(this is not my original language).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set `display:none` in your CSS; the transition logic doesn't seem to activate because of this. Getting rid of this property fixes the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/82kdkt63/

You'll find that now that your submenu is rendered but transparent, it may end up eating mouse clicks that are meant for things underneath it - there are various ways to solve this (including the `pointer-events: none` CSS property)

Overall you'll find that setting css properties directly with javascript is not as nice as adding and removing CSS classes - I recommend that approach.

Comment: Here's another fiddle showing the use of DOM attributes to handle state: https://jsfiddle.net/j35vatyf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it...
https://jsfiddle.net/61haxkh2/6/

I used straight css to get the effect it sounds like you wanted. All I did was add these two bits to your css and I gave the "c" menu link a id of "c".

```
#child{
transition: all .3s;
}

#c:hover > #child{
    opacity:1;
}
```